# Dynamic Resizing Table inside fixed DIV

Tags: jquery, css, resize, html-table

I have a table inside a fixed header and I would like it to be dynamically re-size when the window is being re-sized.

The DIV that contains the table (topTable in the code) works perfectly when you re-size the window, but the table doesn't re-size properly, it does to a certain point but after X-width the whole table moves down!.

Any idea how to:

1. Make the table width the same as its parent container?
2. More important, how to re-size the table properly when window resize?.

What I had tried:

1. I had tried to setup the width of the table = parent's container: `$('#topTable').height($('#topRightContainer').height());`
2. When I create the resizeDic() function, I put  the table ID in there: 
   `$("# (...), #topTable").width(widthA);`

My code is a lit bit long, here's a JFiddle File : http://jsfiddle.net/japeljoff/SnPC5/1/

***HTML :***

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="topContainer">
        <div id="topLeftContainer"></div>
        <div id="topRightContainer">
            <table id="topTable" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="">Practice</th>
                <th colspan="">Leadership</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="">Learning</th>
                <th colspan="">Something1</th>
                <th colspan="">Something2</th>
                <th colspan="">Managing</th>
                <th colspan="">Leading</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="">Intern Arc</th>
                <th colspan="">Arc 1</th>
                <th colspan="">Arc 2</th>
                <th colspan="">Associate</th>
                <th colspan="">Senior Associate</th>
                <th colspan="">Partner</th>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomContainer">
        <div id="bottomLeftContainer">
        </div>
        <div id="bottomRightContainer">
            <!--<div id="bottomRight-LeftContainer"></div>
            <div id="bottomRight-RightContainer"></div>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

***Jquery:***

```
var containerWidth = $("#container").width();
    /*- Set up the width in BottomContainer & TopContainer according to Container's width-*/    
    $('#topContainer').width(containerWidth);
    $('#bottomContainer').width(containerWidth);

    /*- Set up the Margin Top on the BottomContainer to be just below the fixed header-*/
    $('#bottomContainer').css('margin-top', ($('#topContainer').height() + 1));

    /*- Distribute width space: 15% for LeftContainer & 85% for Rigth Container-*/
    $('#topLeftContainer').width(containerWidth * 0.15 );
    $('#topRightContainer').width(containerWidth * 0.85 );
    /*- Distribute width space: 15% for LeftContainer & 85% for Rigth Container-*/
    $('#bottomLeftContainer').width(containerWidth* 0.15);
    $('#bottomRightContainer').width(containerWidth* 0.85);

    $('#topTable').height($('#topRightContainer').height());



function resizeDiv() {
    var widthA = $(window).width() - 30; 
    if(widthA >= 500){

    $("#bottomContainer, #topContainer, #topRightContainer, #bottomRightContainer").width(widthA);

    }
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeDiv()
});

$(window).load(function() {
    resizeDiv()
});
```

***CSS:***

```
#container {    
    width:800px;
    height:100%;
    /*background-color:red;*/
    position:relative;padding-right:50px;

}

#topContainer{
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100px;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    min-width:80px;
    width:1px;
    }

#bottomContainer{

    background-color:grey;
    height:300px;
    width:1px;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    min-width:100px;

}
#extra{background-color:green;height:10px;
    border:1px red solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;}

#topLeftContainer {
     background-color:#222222;
     height:100%;
     float:left;
}

#topRightContainer {
    background-color:#99281A;
    height:100%;
    min-width:80px!important;
}

#topTable{
    background-color:white;
    min-width:80px!important;
    border-collapse:collapse;

}
```

If you need more info, or be more clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying way too hard. Tables can easily be fluid without all that JavaScript, as yours is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/SnPC5/2/

What I've done is to remove #topLeftContainer, which seems to serve no purpose, and set the table's width to 100%. A little more styling would get the black box back that was #topLeftContainer.

```
#topTable {
    width: 100%;
}

<div id="container">
    <div id="topContainer">
        <div id="topRightContainer">
            <table id="topTable" border="1">
                ...
```

With some responsive CSS through media queries you'd be able to get the table flowing down to a smaller width.

Comment: That works perfect! unfortunately, i need the left container. the  table's div container needs to be 85% of the top Container.

Comment: You can get it working with the left container. I'd look for a simpler way to accomplish your layout. It's pretty complex and probably needn't be.

Answer (score 0):

**min-width** on **topRightContainer** and **topTable** are not enough to hold the contents of the table. Since the contents occupy more space, the table is moving to the next line when the window is resized over a certain width. I can think of these options:

1. **word-break:break-all on #topTable** which would break the words on resizing the window beyond the size of the contents, but it would add height since the text would wrap to a new line. Its not the optimal solution since the words break and wrap up into next line making it less meaningful to read.
2. Set **white-space:nowrap on table** and increase the minimum width setting on topTable and topRightContainer to fit the contents. Scrollbar will automatically appear on resizing the window and you can scroll to the contents.
3. **Reduce the font-size of the contents** on resizing the window to fit the table within the DIV.